# Gatsby pathPrefix without hardcoding

Tags: gatsby

The Gatsby docs for [path prefix](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/) show I can define something like `pathPrefix: "/blog"`, and indeed I tried it and it just worked. However, I'd rather not hardcode the path where the app will live. I'd like to be able to deploy the build to multiple paths and have it just work from all of them. I'm hoping there's a way I can make the build work from any arbitrary path. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gatsby-link](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-link/) to help you with that. It functions like React-Router's `Link` component, but helps you out with path prefixing. For example, if you set your `pathPrefix: "/myBlog"`...

```
import Link from 'gatsby-link'

/* later down in the code... */

<nav>
  <Link to='/about'>About The Blog</Link>
</nav>
```

Which would output:

```
<a href="/myBlog/about">About The Blog</a>
```

Comment: The issue is I don't want to hardcode myBlog _anywhere_ in the source, not even in a config file. Conceptually I want the pathPrefix to be "." -- that is, relative to the app's path, so that the app could be deployed at any arbitrary path and still work.

Comment: You could get away with relative links then? e.g. use `<a href="/about">About</a>` and it should work, no matter the path.

Comment: It's not just about links. It's also about loading resources like the JS files themselves.

Comment: Can you programmatically set `pathPrefix` to the parent directory name within you gatsby-config.js file? I'm new to Gatsby, but for links to be resolved _something_ needs to know your site's absolute path.

Comment: @JonathanMellman - this is as close as you can get I assume, but it's not enough, because this happens in build time, while the path might be determined later. A regular HTML page doesn't know what is its path, it just know that the rest of the static content is inside its folder. You can take this folder and drop it any where, and it will work, unless it's Gatsby.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in the `gatsby-config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: process.env.PREFIX
}
```

Then run `PREFIX=/blog gatsby build`.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19481#issuecomment-554430699